# How do I implement a C# createTemplate() method in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm writing a messaging tool where I can send mass emails. I want to add some templates for sending the message twice or several times. But I don't know how to create these templates. I need to write the method in the repository and I have some controllers services and service interfaces. Can you please tell me where should I add which code?

My model looks like this:

```
[DbTable("TEMPLATE", typeof(SqlConnectionProvider))]
public class TEMPLATE : DbTableModel, I_TEMPLATE
{
    [DbColumn(SqlDbType.Int, NotNull = true, PrimaryKey = true, 
        Identity = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

    [DbColumn(SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000, NotNull = true, PrimaryKey = 
        true, Identity = true)]
        public string Nachricht { get; set; }

    [DbColumn(SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, NotNull = true, PrimaryKey = 
        true, Identity = true)]
        public string Betreff { get; set; }
}
```

I tried some things but not one of them works and I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Could you please explain `"sending the message twice or several times"` when and what email templete you would like to send?

Comment: So it just describes the application which I want. So when I should create templates and then i can choose a template in the template View. So i can use the template several times to send  the same message several times.

Comment: Do you have any format in your mind how it might be so that it would eaiser to assist.

Comment: what do you mean by format?

Comment: `" I can choose a template in the template View`"  I mean this actually.

Comment: I created some screenshots: https://ibb.co/7NNk1wY https://ibb.co/C6zZP8Q you can select a template on the droptown "test" or you can create a new.